# Merging Multiple Shapefile Polygons in R

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon, merge

I have a regional shapefile of England and Wales but without containing Scotland and Northern Ireland.

[image: Regions]

I want to add the outlines of Scotland and Northern Ireland in without regional divisions so the combined would consist of the following polygons:

- London
- North-West
- North-East
- East of England
- East Midlands
- West Midlands
- South-West
- South-East
- Yorkshire & The Humber
- Scotland
- Northern Ireland

I have a separate shapefile with just the country border of Scotland and Ireland - my question is it possible to add this to my regions map and if so how can I do so in R?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the `sp` package classes for your data or the newer `sf` classes? Do you care about attributes of your regions (like names, populations etc)? Have you tried reading them in and using `rbind` because these things should behave like data frames.

Comment: @Spacedman I'm using `sp` still. My shapefile doesn't contain many other attributes - those come from a spatial points file which I can then join on later if that makes sense?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `rbind` to combine spatial data objects:

Read in a couple of shapefiles:

```
> la = readOGR(".","la")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: ".", layer: "la"
with 12035 features
It has 4 fields
> pr = readOGR(".","pr")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: ".", layer: "pr"
with 12786 features
It has 3 fields
```

Try using `rbind`:

```
> lapr = rbind(la,pr)
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

This has failed because there's a different number of columns in each shapefile - you can't put data with four columns (fields) with data that has three columns:

```
> names(la)
[1] "POSTCODE" "UPP"      "PC_AREA"  "N"       
> names(pr)
[1] "POSTCODE" "UPP"      "PC_AREA"
```

Fix this some way. I'll remove the `N` column from `la`:

```
> la$N=NULL
```

And now it works:

```
> lapr = rbind(la,pr)
```

Giving me an object with the total features:

```
> dim(lapr)
[1] 24821     3
```

So you do need to make sure your objects have identically-named columns, which you'll have to do by removing, adding, or renaming columns. Then you can `rbind` them together.

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, just seen this - amazing. Could you expand a bit on how to get past the non identical columns issue? My two shapefiles appear to have entirely different columns in the data slot. Do I just need to create dummy columns with the same name in each shapefile so that they match?

Comment: Something like that. If there are columns you don't need, delete them (assign to NULL) and if there are columns with similar names for the same thing (eg "NAME" and "Name") then set the names to the same in one or the other, and if there are names that make no sense in one but you want to keep in the other then create a dummy.

Comment: Worked like a charm @Spacedman! One more question if you don't mind - can I delete attributes from a shapefile in the same way as I can delete columns? To explain, I wanted to find a northern ireland coastline shapefile but can't seem to find one without a local breakdown. What I may have to do is get one including the 4 provinces - Ulster, Leinster, Munster & Connaught, and just delete all but the first - can this be done simply?

Comment: You mean delete *features*? Yes, do: `ulster = counties[1,]`

Comment: Following your fab advice I was able to stich together N.Ireland with Scotland, Ireland and Wales! The only thing I'm not sure about is why, in the list of features, there are like 15 for Scotland and 1 each for the english counties - my last question is will this matter when I go about choroplething this map? I've posted an image of what I mean above @Spacedman

Comment: Work out which row all the "Scotlands" are and try plotting them individually. They might all be the same thing, in which case drop all but one, or they might be bits of Scotland (mainland, skye, mull, shetland....) in which case you might want to merge them....

Comment: Ahh I think the islands are causing there to be more rows. When you say merge @Spacedman do you mean dissolving the separate ones?